# "ImportError: No module named 'win32api'" when "import rpy2.robjects"

Tags: python, winapi, rpy2

I get error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       import rpy2.robjects
>     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects__init__.py", line 15, in 
>       import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
>     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface__init__.py", line 72, in 
>       import win32api
>   ImportError: No module named 'win32api'

when I try

```
import rpy2.robjects
```

I have installed latest versions of both pywin32 and rpy2 for 64 bit Windows:

pywin32-219-cp34-none-win_amd64

rpy2-2.5.6-cp34-none-win_amd64

Please give me advice.

Comment: Can you do `import win32api` from a Python terminal?

Comment: Yes, I can run `import win32api` from terminal.

Comment: That makes very little sense then. One wonders how `import win32api` can succeed sometimes, but not others.

Comment: I can not understand too. It's very strange error with `import win32api` when pywin32 is installed. I'm going to reinstall both packages.

Comment: @Yanita , did u solve the problem?

Comment: @twfx, yes problem was solved. But I can not exactly say in which way. I removed both packages and install them again. After this manipulation rpy2 works in proper way.